# .htaccess hide subfolder url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I've WordPress site with the URL :
http://thelaptopsolutions.in/Laptop%20Solution/

This is working fine but the URL now shows `http://thelaptopsolutions.in/Laptop%20Solution/` but I want it to show `http://thelaptopsolutions.in`

Here's my current htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Laptop%20Solution/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Laptop%20Solution/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file? Is `Laptop%20Solution` a physical subdirectory in which WordPress is installed? (In which case I assume your `.htaccess` file is also in this subdirectory?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you against messing up the contents of the .htaccess file. Revert the changes that you've made to this file and follow the simple procedue.

1. Login to the admin dashboard.
2. Go to Settings > General
3. In the WordPress Address (URL) field type http://www.example.com/site
4. In the Site Address (URL) field type http://www.example.com

Save the changes and you should be good to go.